# Sub contractor engineering works

Tags: resignation, india

I am working for this company for six months. I also signed a labor contract for two years. But here every month I face a salary issue. They are delaying the salary, sometimes up to two months. Now I get another main contractor office with a good salary. More than this one. And also ready to support me.

My current office are blackmailing me about the labor contract. They are not ready for me to leave from there.

How can I leave smoothly?

Comment: Based on my limited understanding of Indian labour law they can't legally prevent you from leaving, they can only require you to work out the (relatively long) notice period. Are they refusing to let you leave earlier than that or is there something else going on?

Comment: If you are being paid 2 months passed the agreed upon interval, I would think they are in breach of contract.  Check you contract.  Most likely this question will get closed....

Answer (score 3):

As this is a question that in part regards Indian law I recommend contacting a lawyer or someone that is specialized in indian law. 
That being said, withholding salary and not paying it until 2 months later sounds sketchy and you could probably argue a breach of contract.

Given that they are not paying you and threatening you with the labour contract I wouldn't be overly concerned about leaving smoothly, they do not appear to be serious in their dealings. I would hand in a resignation stating the last day you will be working and explicitly stating the reason you are leaving, the withholding of your payment.

If you have any outstanding salary with the company you might have to drag it through court if they do not settle.